# Excel - Go from ELSEIF, to a nested IF, then to ELSE

Tags: excel, vba

```
    ElseIf numCol1 = numCol2 Then
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 14 To 33
                If Cells(i, 6) <> "" And Cells(i, 7) = "" Then
                MsgBox "Please indicate if subs are allowed.", vbCritical
                Cancel = True
                Exit Sub
                End If
            Next i
    Else
           'do something
```

If numCol1 = numCol2 it is valid (this is just counting the number of values in each column) and should go to the Else bit
however, I want to check if the cells next to each are filled in rather

E.G.

```
  2               2
Col1            Col2
Value1          Value1
Value2          Value2
```

This is valid, the 2 above each column is the count of how many values are in each column

```
  2               2
Col1            Col2
Value1          Value1
Value2          (blank)
(blank)         Value2
```

This is not valid, even though the count is still two, the last value2 should be in the row above

A bit confusing, but any help is much appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform the validity test for every row. As you point out, simply counting values in each column is unreliable.

Add a formula in a third column. Something like this would work:

```
=IF(A1=B1,0,1)
```

Copy the formula and paste it down to all rows that need to be evaluated.

Now sum the results of all the formulas. If the sum is greater than 0, you have invalid rows.